# Combining multiple probabilities

Tags: probability

I've searched for a while now but didn't find anything that would answer my question precisely, so I've decided to post.

Suppose we have symptoms of various diseases, and after a day the actual diagnosis is 100% known. We have studied numerous past cases and want to make a probabilistic diagnosis for new patients coming in.

(The data is made up to illustrate the problem)

Possible diseases:
D1 = Common cold
D2 = Strep throat
D3 = Malaria

Of all the past cases studied, 
Symptom 1 - vomiting:
10% of common cold (D1) patients were vomiting.
40% of strep throat (D2) patients were vomiting.
70% of malaria (D3) patients were vomiting.

Symptom 2 - elevated body temperature:
For common cold (D1), 20% had normal temperature, 70% had slightly elevated temp, 10% had very high temp.
For strep throad (D2), 60% had normal temp, 10% had slightly elevated temp, 30% had very high temp.
For malaria (D3), 10% had normal temp, 20% had slightly elevated temp, 70% had very high temp.

Symptom 3 - dhiarhea:
For common cold (D1), 80% had no dhiarhea, 10% had mild dhiarhea, 10% had bad dhiarhea with dehidration.
For strep throad (D2), 60% had no dhiarhea, 30% had mild dhiarhea, 10% had bad dhiarhea with dehidration.
For malaria (D3), 10% had no dhiarhea, 20% had mild dhiarhea, 70% bad dhiarhea with dehidration.

Now that we know these probabilities, a doctor accepts a patient, for who we can see that he isn't vomiting, has very high body temperature, and mild dhiearhea.
What are the chances for this person of the three different diseases?
(The chances of all three diseases of course should sum up to 100%).

(Not a homework assignment, just trying to figure out for a hobby project)

Comment: You can't really say anything without also specifying the prevalence of the three diseases among the numerous past cases.  (E.g., if malaria is extremely rare, as it is in the U.S., it's unlikely to be the diagnosis no matter what the symptoms.)  Once you've done that, you can bring Bayes Theorem to bear.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I think you need to go about it:

You have $18$ possible combinations of symptoms: vomit/novomit, low/med/high temp, no/mild/severe diarrhea.
When you multiply out the probabilities of each combination of symptoms, you therefore end up with $18$ probabilities (for each disease).  The probability of a cold sufferer displaying "vomit, no temp, no diarrhea", for example, is $0.1\times 0.2 \times 0.8 = 0.016 = 1.6\%$. (When you add up the probabilities of each of the $18$ combinations, you get $100\%$.)

Since there are three diseases in play, you have $3$ different probabilities for each combination of symptoms.  As seen above, the chance that someone with a cold has "vomit, no temp, no diarrhea" is $1.6\%$, the chance that someone with strep has those symptoms is $14.4\%$, and the chance that someone with malaria has those symptoms is $0.7\%$.  So, when someone with those symptoms shows up, there is a $\dfrac{1.6}{1.6+14.4+0.7} = 9.58\%$ likelihood that they have a cold; similarly, an $86.23\%$ chance of strep, and a $4.19\%$ chance of malaria.